# How to get the view angle (pitch & yaw) of a YouTube 360 video

Tags: youtube-api

I'd like to know how to get the view angle of a YouTube 360 video. I've been searching all over the place but cannot seem to find anything and now I doubt it's even possible. If someone knows more please do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible to get via the YouTube player API yet, but there is a feature request on [YouTube's issue tracker here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7547).

Comment: Such a shame. Did you have to search deep for this? I couldn't find any information anywhere.

Comment: I'm YouTube DevRel :-)  In the future you can search the issue tracker for known bugs and feature requests here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=API%3DYouTube